# how to add value in top attribute in every 5 second using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a jquery function whose purpose is to add a padding in every 5 seconds but it working only once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function aniMation(){

    var top=0;
    var left=0;

    $('#frame').css({top:++top,left:++left})

    }


$(function (){

    setInterval(aniMation,5000)

    })


</script>



<body>

<div class="main">
<div id="frame">
text

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call setInterval(aniMation,5000) from aniMation() also, like this...

```
function aniMation(){
var top=0;
var left=0;

$('#frame').css({top:++top,left:++left})
  setInterval(aniMation,5000);
}
```

Comment: can u tell me why is setInterval not working out side the function

Comment: You were calling setInterval(aniMation,5000); only once on page ready and you have to call it repeatedly by calling in aniMation() we made it to call again and again like recursive function. You can have termination condition in this function if required

Answer (score 1):

```
function aniMation(){
    var top=0;
    var left=0;
    $('#frame').css({top:++top,left:++left});
    setTimeout(aniMation , 5000);
}
```

*Update why your code was not working* :

You are using short-hand for `$(document).ready( function() { somecode; });` as:

```
$(function (){
    setInterval(aniMation,5000);
});
```

And that will be executed when the page loads properly (only once). So I have made the change in your `aniMation` function to call itself recursively.

Comment: thank for solution but can u tell me why my code is not working what is the reason behind

Answer (score 1):

You only call setTimeout once.
I suggest to call setTimeout at the end of aniMation if the function should continue.
I wouldn't suggest to use setInterval.

Comment: Most don't call clearInterval(). setTimeout is more defensive. I put my functions in try catch and if something goes wrong, they stop running automatically without the need to call something.

Answer (score 1):

Make your top and left variables global, because you reiniti it every time and every iteration you have vcalue 1 for both. In case of global you will increment it:

```
var top=0;
var left=0;

function aniMation(){
    $('#frame').css({top:++top,left:++left})
}


$(function () {
    setInterval(aniMation,5000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like so:

```
var f   = $('#frame'), 
    top = 0, left = 0;

function aniMation(){
    f.css({top: (++top)+ 'px', left: (++left) + 'px'})    
}
```

your example just works once because every time you execute the function `top` and `left` properties are reset to 0.

Also, it's better to create an outer reference to the iframe element, so it's not necessary recreating a new one at each function call

Comment: actually i want to add "1" in top and left in every 5 second that is my requirment